# Allow users to use custom domain to my cloudfront app

Tags: ssl, dns, amazon-cloudfront, cname

I have a cloud front app with domain `xyz123.cloudfront.net`. 
This CloudFront is then mapped to domain `sub1.mydomain.com`. For this, I followed these steps.

1. Added SSL through AWS CloudFront pannel to `*.mydomain.com`
2. Added `A` `Alias` record in Route 53 to `xyz123.cloudfront.net`

This makes `sub1.mydomain.com` work perfectly over SSL.

Now, I want to allow my users to use their own domain (eg `sub1.userdomain.com`) to access the app.
This is similar to what [UptimeRobot](https://uptimerobot.com/) allows in its public status pages.

**What I tried, but not working**

- Added `CNAME` to `sub1.userdomain.com` pointing to `xyz123.cloudfront.net`, I get SSL Error
- Added `CNAME` to `sub1.userdomain.com` pointing to `sub1.mydomain.com`, I get SSL Error
- Added `CNAME` to `sub1.userdomain.com` pointing to `xyz123.s3-website.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com` (S3 Static Hosting URL)

**Question**

1. How does UptimeRobot (or GitHub Pages) allow users to add a custom domain to their status page over SSL
2. What is the prerequisite to make this happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no way to add more than 10 custom domains to a SSL in AWS.
Which is a prerequisite to having a custom domain to your cloudfront.

Hence, a workaround this could be as below.
1. Create a S3 single bucket which hosts your code
2. Create Multiple Could front distributions connected to single S3 Bucket
3. Then, add custom domains to these cloud front.

You will also need to think about CORS settings in your API of the app to allow requests from these custom domains.

Answer (score 2):

1. From https://github.blog/2018-05-01-github-pages-custom-domains-https/:

   > We have partnered with the certificate authority Let’s Encrypt on
   >       this project. As supporters of Let’s Encrypt’s mission to make the
   >       web more secure for everyone, we’ve officially become Silver-level
   >       sponsors of the initiative.

   Github pages create a single certificate, from Let's Encrypt, for both your custom `userdomain.com` and `YOURNAME.github.io`. This is possible with a **SAN certificate** (Subject Alternative Name, https://support.dnsimple.com/articles/what-is-ssl-san/).
2. You can't associate more than one SSL certificate to a CloudFront distribution but ACM (AWS Certificate Manager) supports up to 10 subject alternative names. To mimic Github Pages you have to know the user domains beforehand or create a new certificate each time you add a new domain to replace the old one.